# getImageURI() returning a big url that won't open in browser

Tags: php, charts, printing, google-visualization, png

I'm currently converting my google column chart into a png, and then getting the url using `chart_div.innerHTML`, paste it into browser (Firefox).

**My error is** : 413. That’s an error. Your client issued a request that was too large

Is there any way to reduce the size of the url ? or any possible solution around it ? my goal is to be able to convert all of my 4 charts to pngs and print each, or at least 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send the image to a new window,
this will allow you to right click and save as, print, etc...

```
window.open(chart.getImageURI(), '_blank');
```

the above creates a "pop-up" and may be blocked,
you can also change the location of the current page...

```
location.href = chart.getImageURI();
```

see following fiddle for an example...

https://jsfiddle.net/7qtuhwaw/

**EDIT**

an option for chrome is to create a download link,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', '2015');
    data.addColumn('number', '2016');
    data.addRows([
       [new Date('01/01/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('02/01/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('03/01/2016'), 205, 200],
       [new Date('04/01/2016'), 220, 230],
       [new Date('05/01/2016'), 212, 210],
       [new Date('06/01/2016'), 185, 193],
       [new Date('07/01/2016'), 196, 207]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
      downloadLink.href = chart.getImageURI();
      downloadLink.download = 'chart.png';
      downloadLink.click();
    });

    chart.draw(data, {
      hAxis: {
        format: 'MMM'
      },
      height: 400
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="image_div"></div>
```

Comment: It did help indeed, can do as you stated, now i'm trying to add a select handler on the graph it self , so it directly downloads as png like save as, thank you!

Comment: I could put that window.open in the select handler function maybe and the user do it manually save as, opens up many ideas

Comment: It only works on firefox however, chrome is not supported, any idea how can i work it the way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Example solution from google developpers as seen on the issues page of google charts.

Links:

Tutorial : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

Comment: Yes that's the exact example i've used.

Comment: if you paste it into browser (chrome) did it work !?, and why are you posting it in browser why don't you generate png from data:image

Comment: Tried chrome but it doesn't work, i'm not sure what is data:image, but i've tried to output it in document.write, and it shows fine on browser, working on downloading it as png atm

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to Google Servers, you will need to grab the charts in chunks. HTTP 413 means that the server [declined your request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413), because it's just too big. Try splitting your chart into multiple charts and then either put it back together locally or just display the chunks.

Comment: Indeed, i've tried to output in document.write and it worked fine, only download is left now,  either as a png or pdf (probably using tcpdf after researching)