# How to print a GoogleChart in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, charts

I would like to print a new google chart when I click on a button.
I already know how to use google charts but I don't know how to print it in a new tab.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try `window.open()`

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278707/5090771)...

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to just say "send this data to a new tab".

Basically, all you'll do is have a page that'll generate the appropriate chart on it's own. Then, just use `window.open("url-to-page-with-chart")` to open the page with the chart in a new tab.